# How to show Prestashop product price by tag ( i want to divide to 12 or 6 installments with IF )

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need all prestashop products to sell with 6 or 12 installments.

Because I don't see anywhere to do that (even with modules), I guess that I can manipulate the product.tpl to put an IF condition in there to check if product has tag "6X" to show:

```
{convertPrice price=$productPrice / 6|floatval}
```

or if not tag "6X" founded, show with "ELSE"

```
{convertPrice price=$productPrice / 12|floatval}
```

My problem is how to check a prestashop array tags to do that!
Somebody can guide me how to make this work?

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Comment: Is Prestashop 1.6!

Answer (score 0):

Edit product.tpl is incorrect. The product is also present in other tpl and once made ​​shopping the discount would be lost.
PrestaShop does not have a similar management.

I can recommend to create two categories : 6X and 12X, and add in these values ​​to be served

```
SELECT `id_product` FROM `ps_product_tag` WHERE `id_tag`="/*here enter the id of the tag*/"
```

and for each of the id creates:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_category_product`(`id_category`, `id_product`) VALUES (/* id new category */,/*id product*/)
```

Enter area there is a page for your purpose. Go to "price rules" and "Catalog Price Rules". Press "Add new catalog price rule".

From this panel you can decide discounts er category. In principal area select general option and in " Add a new condition group" select the category involved.

The tpl file via tag you can change it so this:

```
{foreach from=Tag::getProductTags($product->id) key=k item=v}
    {foreach from=$v item=value}
            {if $value==6X}
                    {convertPrice price=$productPrice/6|floatval}
            {else}
                    {convertPrice price=$productPrice}
            {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Hi Matteo!, thanks for your great idea. But, i not mention that i need to add some text to show price like "Pay in just 10x of 12$

Comment: That i have added to my product.tpl without problems but like you say, i have to edit too in cart, front-end, etc. Instead of tags, maybe will be useful check for what category are (6x or 12x), to show the price divided by 12 or 6 with, again, IF .. ELSE?

Comment: it breaks the page, but we are near!!!
http://www.electromuebles.com.py/home/12-lavarropas-whirlpool-12kg.html

Comment: Sorry, $product.id_product is used in product-list.tpl. For the page Product.tpl change $product.id_product with $product->id

Comment: $product.price with $productPrice

Comment: `<span id="our_price_display" itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}">
          {foreach from=Tag::getProductTags($product->id) key=k item=v}
              {foreach from=$v item=value}
                  {*$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'*}
                      {if $value==6X}
                             {convertPrice price=$product.price/6|floatval}
                      {else}
                             {convertPrice price=$product.price}
                      {/if}
              {/foreach}
          {/foreach}
           </span>`

Comment: your last message i don't see the difference =)

Comment: <span id="our_price_display" itemprop="price" content="{$productPrice}"> 
 {foreach from=Tag::getProductTags($product->id) key=k item=v} 
  {foreach from=$v item=value} 
   {if $value==6X} 
    {convertPrice price=$productPrice/6|floatval} 
   {else} 
    {convertPrice price=$productPrice} 
   {/if} 
  {/foreach} 
 {/foreach} 
</span>

Comment: It works!!!!! The only thing is that the included taxes are gone! Only shows price with excluded taxes...